# sessionStorage, Variable script breaks

Tags: javascript, session-storage

So, I have pages - A and B. On the page A has a button, when we click on the button opens a page B and opens a hidden block.

I'm certainly doing something wrong, but what?

this template A

```
<script>
$('button').click(function () {

var openHiddenBlock = document.setItem('true');
    sessionStorage.setItem('openHiddenBlock', 'true');

    location.href = "http://B.com";

});
</script>
```

this template B

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(sessionStorage.getItem('true') == 'true') {
        $('HiddenBlock').slideToggle(); // opening animation 
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the expected result, what is the observed behavior?

Comment: um, are A and B on the same domain? Example hints it is a different domain.

Comment: Your call to `.getItem()` is looking for an item named "true", but your call to `.setItem()` calls it "openHiddenBlock".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page B you're testing for an item with the key of "true" but on page A you're setting an item with key "openHiddenBlock".

Comment: Yes, and
var openHiddenBlock = document.setItem('true');
an extra line